# Why won't this for loop execute?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I'm making a simple program that gets the users balance from the entered ID. For some reason the for loop doesn't execute when an ID from the listof_ID array is entered:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int cntr;
    int ID;

    int listof_ID[] = {001, 002, 003, 004, 005};
    float listof_BAL[] = {338.90, 745.87, 897.32, 665.36, 102.45};

    puts("**Check Your Balance** \n");
    printf("**Please Enter Your ID >> ");
    scanf("%d", &ID);
    for(cntr = 0; cntr > 5; cntr++)
    {
        if(ID == listof_ID[cntr])
        {
            puts("Your balance is ");
            printf("%.2f", listof_BAL[cntr]);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cntr > 5 will not happen since it is initialized to 0

Comment: Do you realize that you are initializing `listof_ID[]` with octal literals?  In this case it won't matter, but still, it seems as though you are probably unaware of this.

Comment: @EdS. I wasn't sure if that was the case or not since the number is preceded by two zeros instead of the usual one.

Comment: Next step, branded_ann: accept any answer that seems to be correct. :)

Comment: @TheZ: `std::cout << 0010; // prints "8"`.  All it takes is *one* leading zero, the rest are irrelevant.

Comment: @EdS. Showing versus telling, I like it! +1

Answer (score 7):

```
for(cntr = 0; cntr > 5; cntr++)
```

Should be

```
for(cntr = 0; cntr < 5; cntr++)
```

The loop executes while the condition `cntr > 5` is true. If `cntr` starts at `0` then it is obviously not greater than 5, so the body of the loop never executes.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, the first value of cntr = 0, which means that cntr < 5. But in the condition, you are checking if cntr > 5, which is not true. So, the loop does not start.